# Verifying significance level for hypothesis test functions

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent $N(\mu, 1)$ r.v's such that 
>   $$ H_0: \mu=0, ~~~H_1:\mu \neq 0$$
>   where the tests are as follows$$f_1(x,y) = \begin{cases}
> 1,&|x+y|>a\\
> 0, &|x+y|\le a
> \end{cases}$$
>   and 
>   $$f_2(x,y) = \begin{cases}
> 1,&|x+2y|>b\\
> 0, &|x+2y|\le b
> \end{cases}$$
>   1. Find $a$ and $b$ so that the size is $\alpha=5\%$ for both tests.

1. Since the size of the test is the probability of incorrectly rejecting the null, then we need to find 
   $$P(Reject H_0|\mu=0)=0.05$$
   $$ \iff P(\frac{(X-\mu_0)\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}~~|~\mu=0)=0.05$$
   $$ \iff P(X\sqrt{n})=0.05$$
   I am unsure how to implement the function into this so that I can find $a,b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are test functions. 
A test function $f$, rejects $H_0$ 
if and only if $f=1$. 
That is, you want to find $a$ and $b$ such that that
\begin{align*}
 \begin{cases}
  P(f_1=1|\mu=0) &= \alpha \\
  P(f_2=1|\mu=0) &= \alpha
 \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Note that
\begin{align*}
 P(f_1=1|\mu=0) &= P(|X+Y|>a|\mu=0) \\
                &= P\left(\bigg|\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg| > \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
\end{align*}
Since, under $\mu=0$, $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normals, $Z=\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}$ is a standard normal.
Therefore, you wish $P\left(|Z| > \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\alpha$. This happens if $\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}=\Phi^{-1}(1-2^{-1}\alpha)$, where $\Phi$ is the cdf of the standard normal. Conclude that $a=\sqrt{2}\Phi^{-1}(1-2^{-1}\alpha)$.

Can you use the same reasoning to find $b$?

Comment: Thank-you! So, $b=\sqrt{3}\Phi^{-1}(1-2^{-1}\alpha)$ ?

Comment: Why do you think that is the answer?

Comment: Because $X+2Y \sim N(0,3)$, so to make it standard we divide by $\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: How do you know that X+2Y follows a N(0,3)?

Comment: Are you saying that $2Y \sim N(0,2)$? This fact might be useful, $Var[aX]=a^2 Var[X]$.

Comment: Ah yes. And so $X+2Y \sim N(0,5)$

Comment: Indeed, it is! :D